# 'eGame' is an ambiguous reference between 'GameLogParser.eGame' and 'GuildStats_Shared.eGame'

Tags: c#

Is it posible to tell the compiler this is the same enum, so it can be defined both places?

```
public enum eGame
{
    Error,
    AoC,
    Rift,
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: HUH? Defining the same enum in two places seems like a very strange thing to do. Can you not just place it somewhere more "general" and use it in two places?

Comment: Problem is that its defined in 2 projects, and this is the third using components for all of them. So either big refactor or some work around

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same enum though. The title indicates you have two distinct types

```
GameLogParser.eGame
GuildStats_Shared.eGame
```

Now, if they really contain the same enum names / values, you can do a simple conversion between the two:

```
GameLogParser.eGame firstEnumType = eGame.Error;
int firstValue = (int)firstEnumType;
GuildStats_Shared.eGame second = (GuildStats_Shared.eGame)Enum.ToObject(typeof(GuildStats_Shared.eGame), firstValue);
//second should be "Error"
```

In addition, your title indicates a compile time error because you probably haven't fully namespaced your reference; if you just do this:

```
eGame x = eGame.Error;
```

The compiler doesnt know which type to use. Do something like this:

```
GameLogParser.eGame = GameLogParser.eGame.Error;
```